# Why full join is not working between two sub queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Seems like mysql full join is not working between two sub queries, here is query I have tried.
I may not post my actual query, but here is the model where it gives idea about how I tried and my requirement.

```
select * from (select * from campaign) a full join (select * from usagecount)b using(user_id);
```

Where it works for

```
select * from campaign full join usagecount using(user_id);
```

My question is that, if it(full join) works  when I use between two normal table why it won't work between subqueries.

Comment: MySQL does not support full joins at all.

Comment: But full join works if I use normally. Now with in subqueries.
Please see my edited question

Comment: Your second statement doesn't actually run a full join, it's a regular inner join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2d239/2 vs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c2d23/1